# creating and mapping key values inside mapper is bad practice?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I want to ask, is it poor programming practice to splitting, or making our key value pairs in our mapper class, rather creating its standalone writable class?

I have 10K keys, and their values that are in string format,
I am performing my splitting inside mapper, is it good ? or bad?
if bad then why ? and if not, then in what circumstances it will be bad ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not about a good programming practice. Actually, the framework has been so designed that you have to follow the said rules and guidelines. If the key and value classes are not Writable, then the program would not compile and would return an error.

```
The key and value classes have to be serializable by the framework and hence need to 
implement the Writable interface. Additionally, the key classes have to implement the 
WritableComparable interface to facilitate sorting by the framework.
```

Hence, for that reason, you cannot use String as a key class. Rather you can use Text for that matter.
You can access this tutorial as well to see more Tutorial(http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable1/mapred_tutorial.html)

Comment: okkey, i have another question, asked tommorow on stackoverflow, i'll send u the link, then please tell me what synario should i use.. okey..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967190/create-custom-inputformat-of-columnfamilyinputformat-for-cassandra according to this question , what should be the best implimentation, my code is working, on single node..